# iOS In App Purchase Not returning all products

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

After I was able to get my In App Purchase helper class to work for 1 product, I tried to add additional products to my app. It has been more than 2 days and the code (in sandbox) is still returning 1 product from this call

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

There is one thing that I did that could have triggered this and I am not sure how to fix it. I turned off "Hosting Content with Apple" option for my first IAP product because I realized that I did not need this (I already uploaded the .pkg and was able to get it working and I deleted it). I then created 2 more products with that same setting turned off... Do I need to upload a dummy pkg to get those 2 other products working as well?

Comment: Obvious question, but are you passing all of the potential products in to SKProductsRequest initWithProductIdentifiers:?

Comment: We all have those days

Comment: you can write your comment as an answer and i can accept.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pass all of the potential products in to  SKProductsRequest initWithProductIdentifiers:.